# Where is the location using android File access with cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova

I just started using phonegap for android app development.  I am trying to write to a file using code like this (following phonegag example).

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function writeText(file, text) {
    fileName = file;
    textToWrite = text;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
  writer.seek(writer.length);
  writer.write(textToWrite);
  console.log("Output: " + textToWrite);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

In the android emulator with Eclipse as debugger, I can see the lines were executed (log line printed out).  No errors anywhere.  However, I could not find the file in my system.  Where should the file go?  Can I look at it in Windows?

Here is how I call the writer.
    writeText("test.txt", "ending ...");

Where is the file test.txt?  Or, maybe I completely got it wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hey man you find it yet? :~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe PhoneGap will place the file in `/mnt/storage/sdcard0` on the device.

For emulator you can find it by doing this -

1. Switch to **DDMS** perspective
2. Select the emulator in **devices** list, whose sdcard you want to explore.
3. Open **File Explorer** tab on right hand side.
4. Expand tree structure. **mnt/sdcard/**

[image]

I suggest putting a callback function inside your `gotFileWriter` to know exactly when the write has finished -

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log('write has finished');
    };
    writer.seek(writer.length);
    writer.write(textToWrite);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That led me to a whole new "perspective" :-).  But the file is not there.  I have got both read/write working so I know the file is persisting correctly.  It would still be nice to access the file from the DDMS perspective.

Answer (score 2):

The location being written on my device (Cordova 3.3) is `/storage/sdcard0` but it's also in `/storage/emulated/legacy`.

You can find the location by logging the `dir.filePath` when the file is written

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null); 

function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) { 
  var entry=fileSystem.root; 
  entry.getDirectory("directory", {create: true, exclusive: true}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
} 

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) { 
   console.log("Created directory "+ dir.name + ", FilePath: "+ dir.fullPath);
} 

function onGetDirectoryFail(error) { 
   console.log("Error creating directory "+error.code); 
}
```

Hope that helps!